# Mock object did not update value

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am setting an `int` value like this:

```
when(status.getCurrentSeq()).thenReturn(0);
```

When test case runs code logic sets value of CurrentSeq to 1.

```
status.setCurrentSeq(1)
```

But `currentSeq` remains `0` in mock object. Getting `status.getCurrentSeq()` again always return `0`.

Comment: Seems like you are mixing mock behavior with real behavior.

Comment: Maybe you can show us the whole unit test and try to explain what behaviour exactly are you trying to test.

Comment: Its a recursion. On the base of updated value, next logic executes. If it did not update from 0 to 1; then same logic executes each time and code runs forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set a value on a mocked object. It will still return what it has been mocked to return. In this case 0.

Why would you even need to mock the method to return 0 if you do not want it to return 0?
Perhaps removing the `when(status.getCurrentSeq()).thenReturn(0);` altogether would fix your problem.

EDIT:
Maybe stubbing consecutive calls is what you need?

```
when(status.getCurrentSeq())
  .thenReturn(0)
  .thenReturn(1);
```

It can also be shortened like this:

```
when(status.getCurrentSeq())
  .thenReturn(0,1);
```

This behaviour can be verified with:

```
assertEquals(0, status.getCurrentSeq());
assertEquals(1, status.getCurrentSeq());
assertEquals(1, status.getCurrentSeq());
```

It will return 0 the first time the mocked method is called and 1 on every consecutive call.

Comment: Its a recursion. On the base of updated value, next logic executes. If it did not update from 0 to 1; then same logic executes each time.

Comment: It's still unclear to me why would you need to mock it then?

Comment: Did you mean that I should not mock this object? Using Mockito is a good practice for writing test cases.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is a good practice but sometimes people go overboard with it and are not testing any logic at all if everything is mocked. :) That's why I though it would be a good idea to see your exact test-case.
Look at my edit, maybe this could be of help.

Comment: Stubbing consecutive calls did not help. It always return 1. But I need it to return 0 for the first time.

Comment: Stubbing consecutive calls that way should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82492/discussion-between-imran-tariq-and-reins).